# Filling an area under curve until a x value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to color the area below the curve until the x value = 3500 (the red y x constant) but I can't manage to doit. I tried with fillbetween() method but it didn't worked.

[image]

This is my code for plotting

```
# Se define toda la generación 
G_T = sum([300,500,1000,400,1400,500,600])
G = np.arange(-1,G_T,0.01) 
P = [0,20,32,41,44,50,70,100] # Precios   
P_y = np.zeros((G.shape[0]))

# Vector de precios
P_y[(G>=0) & (G<=300)] = P[1]  
P_y[(G>300) & (G<=800)] = P[2] 
P_y[(G>800) & (G<=1800)] = P[3]
P_y[(G>1800) & (G<=2200)] = P[4] 
P_y[(G>2200) & (G<=3600)] = P[5]
P_y[(G>3600) & (G<=4100)] = P[6]
P_y[(G>4100) & (G<=4700)] = P[7] 


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10)) 

plt.plot(G,P_y)      

plt.vlines(3500,0,50,'red')
plt.title('Curva de oferta agregada')
plt.xticks([0,300,800,1800,2200,3600,4100,4700]) 
plt.yticks(P) 
plt.ylabel('USD/MW')
plt.xlabel('USD') 

plt.text(110, 22, 'G5', fontsize=9)
plt.text(500, 33, 'G1', fontsize=9) 
plt.text(1250, 42, 'G2', fontsize=9) 
plt.text(1950, 45, 'G3', fontsize=9) 
plt.text(2900, 51, 'G4', fontsize=9) 
plt.text(3800, 71, 'G6', fontsize=9) 
plt.text(4350, 101, 'G7', fontsize=9)  

plt.grid()
# plt.savefig('Curva.eps', format='eps')
plt.show()
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
plt.fill_between([0, 300, 800, 1800, 2200, 3500], P[:6], step='pre')
```

[image]

---

Note: it is slightly easier and more flexible if the x-steps were coded in a variable, not hardcoded as they are now in the `P_Y` list, or the list that calculates `G_T`. If these values were stored in a variable, you could use `xvals[:5] + [3500]` instead of the above list (you need the `+ [3500]`, since otherwise the last value would be 3600).